# Getting Undefined property: Laravel\Scout\Builder::$whereIns error

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout, typesense

I am using Laravel scout with Typesense package for searching purpose. I have self-hosted my Typesense server and then imported the Model on scout but when i try to access the data, I'm getting this error.

[image]
This is the query that giving me error

```
$result = Todo::search('test')->get();
```

i have added these following methods on my Todo model

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    return array_merge(
        $this->toArray(), 
        [
            // Cast id to string and turn created_at into an int32 timestamp
            // in order to maintain compatibility with the Typesense index definition below
            'id' => (string) $this->id,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at->timestamp,
        ]
    );
}

 /**
 * The Typesense schema to be created.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getCollectionSchema(): array {
    return [
        'name' => $this->searchableAs(),
        'fields' => [
            [
                'name' => 'id',
                'type' => 'string',
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'title',
                'type' => 'string',
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'created_at',
                'type' => 'int64',
            ],
        ],
        'default_sorting_field' => 'created_at',
    ];
}

 /**
 * The fields to be queried against. See https://typesense.org/docs/0.24.0/api/search.html.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function typesenseQueryBy(): array {
    return [
        'id','title'
    ];
}
```

Here is the error message in text form

```
 #message: "Method Laravel\Scout\Builder::getCollection does not exist."
```

Any suggestion or help would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Please share more details, like the error messages **in text form**

Comment: Also, did you try to search for existing issues about this? I've found one at https://github.com/typesense/laravel-scout-typesense-driver/issues/69, and maybe you are using an outdated version of that library?

Comment: provided the error message in text form.

not sure whether the version i'm using is outdated or not. i am using this package https://github.com/typesense/laravel-scout-typesense-driver
and in my composer.json this is the version
"typesense/laravel-scout-typesense-driver": "^5.2",

Comment: Why not check whether you can upgrade that package?

Comment: i just installed this package today. that's why i think its the latest one.

Comment: If you are still facing problems with that package, why not report this at their bug tracker? That's something you should not fix on your own

Comment: Ok. thanks @NicoHaase . will do the same. There is already a issue logged in github but its closed without any answer. added comment on it.
https://github.com/typesense/laravel-scout-typesense-driver/issues/69